# Private chat using Firebase like WhatsApp

Tags: android, firebase, chat, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement a private chat Android app using Firebase, but I'm stuck at the implementation of the private chat.

I'm using this [GitHub lib](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat). This this demo is providing a group chat, but what I want to implement is one-on-one chat.

Is this possible using Firebase or not? If yes, then how can I achieve it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample for firebase:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#7

Firebase is great and you can build 1-1 or group chat using it, however you will have to work on lot of other things from online/offline status, typing indicator, group chat, emoticons, file upload, image/audio/video attachment, designing UI layout, handling notifications, status updates  and many other things required to have a complete WhatsApp chat solution. Have a look at the open source code for [Kommunicate Chatbot SDK in Github](https://github.com/Kommunicate-io/Kommunicate-Android-Chat-SDK) which contains chat screen code.

Comment: Github repo link is broken...

Comment: updated with new repo link